# Iterate over a string 2 (or n) characters at a time in Python

Tags: python, iteration

Earlier today I needed to iterate over a string 2 characters at a time for parsing a string formatted like `"+c-R+D-E"` (there are a few extra letters).

I ended up with this, which works, but it looks ugly.  I ended up commenting what it was doing because it felt non-obvious.  It almost seems pythonic, but not quite.

```
# Might not be exact, but you get the idea, use the step
# parameter of range() and slicing to grab 2 chars at a time
s = "+c-R+D-e"
for op, code in (s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)):
  print op, code
```

Are there some better/cleaner ways to do this?

Comment: @Richard, may be u miss a ")" on line 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't know about cleaner, but there's another alternative:

```
for (op, code) in zip(s[0::2], s[1::2]):
    print op, code
```

A no-copy version:

```
from itertools import izip, islice
for (op, code) in izip(islice(s, 0, None, 2), islice(s, 1, None, 2)):
    print op, code
```

Comment: I really like this one...i just wish it didn't make copies to iterate over.

Comment: The zip approach skips the last character in case the string has odd number of characters.

Comment: For python3 the "no-copy version" is not necessary (and is actually no longer valid).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659552/importing-izip-from-itertools-module-gives-nameerror-in-python-3-x

Comment: Slices are still copies in Python 3, so you still need `islice`.

Comment: Generalizing the idea, in Python 3 you can write: `for ... in zip(*(islice(s, i, None, n) for i in range(n))):`

Answer (score 18):

Maybe this would be cleaner?

```
s = "+c-R+D-e"
for i in xrange(0, len(s), 2):
    op, code = s[i:i+2]
    print op, code
```

You could perhaps write a generator to do what you want, maybe that would be more pythonic :)

Comment: +1 simple and it works for any n (if ValueError exception is handled when len(s) is not a multiple of n.

Answer (score 6):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
def main():
    s = "+c-R+D-e"
    for item in grouper(s, 2):
        print ' '.join(item)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
##output
##+ c
##- R
##+ D
##- e
```

`izip_longest` requires Python 2.6( or higher). If on Python 2.4 or 2.5, use the definition for `izip_longest` from the [document](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip%5Flongest) or change the grouper function to:

```
from itertools import izip, chain, repeat
def grouper(iterable, n, padvalue=None):
    return izip(*[chain(iterable, repeat(padvalue, n-1))]*n)
```

Comment: Best answer, except it's renamed to `zip_longest` [in Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Answer (score 6):

[Triptych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43089/triptych) inspired this more general solution:

```
def slicen(s, n, truncate=False):
    assert n > 0
    while len(s) >= n:
        yield s[:n]
        s = s[n:]
    if len(s) and not truncate:
        yield s

for op, code in slicen("+c-R+D-e", 2):
    print op,code
```

Answer (score 5):

Great opportunity for a generator.  For larger lists, this will be much more efficient than zipping every other elemnent.  Note that this version also handles strings with dangling `op`s

```
def opcodes(s):
    while True:
        try:
            op   = s[0]
            code = s[1]
            s    = s[2:]
        except IndexError:
            return
        yield op,code        


for op,code in opcodes("+c-R+D-e"):
   print op,code
```

edit: minor rewrite to avoid ValueError exceptions.

Comment: A few edge cases - always raises ValueError: try opcodes("a1")

Answer (score 3):

This approach support an arbitrary number of elements per result, evaluates lazily, and the input iterable can be a generator (no indexing is attempted):

```
import itertools

def groups_of_n(n, iterable):
    c = itertools.count()
    for _, gen in itertools.groupby(iterable, lambda x: c.next() / n):
        yield gen
```

Any left-over elements are returned in a shorter list.

Example usage:

```
for g in groups_of_n(4, xrange(21)):
    print list(g)

[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19]
[20]
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers work well for n = 2, but for the general case you could try this:

```
def slicen(s, n, truncate=False):
    nslices = len(s) / n
    if not truncate and (len(s) % n):
        nslices += 1
    return (s[i*n:n*(i+1)] for i in range(nslices))

>>> s = '+c-R+D-e'
>>> for op, code in slicen(s, 2):
...     print op, code
... 
+ c
- R
+ D
- e

>>> for a, b, c in slicen(s, 3):
...     print a, b, c
... 
+ c -
R + D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

>>> for a, b, c in slicen(s,3,True):
...     print a, b, c
... 
+ c -
R + D
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer, a little bit cleaner to my eyes:

```py
for i in range(0, len(string) - 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print string[i:i+2]
```

Comment: `range` does support a step too ;) -- `for i in range(0, len(str), 2): print str[i:i+2]`

Answer (score 2):

Consider `pip` installing [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), which already ships with a [`chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) implementation along with other helpful tools:

```
import more_itertools 

for op, code in more_itertools.chunked(s, 2):
    print(op, code)
```

Output:

```
+ c
- R
+ D
- e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = "+c-R+D-e"
>>> s
'+c-R+D-e'
>>> s[::2]
'+-+-'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most efficient, but if you like regexes...

```
import re
s = "+c-R+D-e"
for op, code in re.findall('(.)(.)', s):
    print op, code
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  Ended doing something like this:

```
ops = iter("+c-R+D-e")
for op in ops
    code = ops.next()

    print op, code
```

I felt it was the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

I made this simple generator:

```py
def every_two(s):
    d = list(s)
    c = True
    for i in range(len(d)):
        if c:
            c = False
            yield d[i], d[i+1]
        else:
            c = True
```

It will raise an IndexError if the lenght of the string isn't divisible by two but you can just wrap the yield statement in a try block.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer on the platform. But for this question, an answer working for all `n` would be helpful

Comment: Answer is incorrect