# Encoding Arabic letters with their diacritics (if exists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm working on a deep learning project in which we use RNN. I want to encode the data before it's fed to the network. Input is Arabic verses, which have diacritics that are treated as separate characters in Python. I should encode/represent the character with the character following it with a number **if the character following it is a diacritic, else I only encode the character**.

Doing so for millions of verses, was hoping to use `lambda` with `map`. However, I cannot iterate with two characters at a time, i.e., was hoping for:

```
map(lambda ch, next_ch: encode(ch + next_ch) if is_diacritic(next_ch) else encode(ch), verse)
```

My intention behind the question is finding the fastest way to accomplish the above. No restriction on lambda functions, but `for` loop answers are not what I'm looking for.

A close example for non-Arabians, assume you want to encode the following text:

```
 XXA)L_I!I%M<LLL>MMQ*Q
```

You want to encode the letter after concatenating it with the letter following it **if it's a special character**, else just encode the letter only.

Output:

```
['X', 'X', 'A)', 'L_', 'I!', 'I%', 'M<', 'L', 'L', 'L>', 'M', 'M', 'Q*', 'Q']
```

For Arabians:

Verse example:

"قفا نبك من ذِكرى حبيب ومنزل بسِقطِ اللّوى بينَ الدَّخول فحَوْمل"

Diacritics are these small symbols above the letter(i.e., ّ , ْ )

---

[Update]

[Range of diacritics](https://unicode-table.com/en/#arabic) starts at [64B HEX or 1611 INT](https://unicode-table.com/en/#064B) and ends at [652 HEX or 1618 INT](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0652).

And letters [621 HEX - 1569 INT](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0621) to [63A HEX - 1594 INT](https://unicode-table.com/en/#063A) and from [641 HEX - 1601 INT](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0641) to [64A HEX - 1610 INT](https://unicode-table.com/en/#064A)

**A letter can have at most one diacritic.**

---

Extra information:

A similar encoding methodology to what I'm doing is representing the binary form of the verse as a matrix with shape `(number of bits needed, number of characters in a verse)`. Both the number of bits and number of characters are calculated **after we combine each letter with its diacritic if it exists**.

For example, assume the verse is the following, and diacritics are special characters:

```
X+Y_XX+YYYY_
```

The alphabet different combinations are:

```
['X', 'X+', 'X_', 'Y', 'Y+', 'Y_']
```

Hence I need `3` bits *(at least)* to represent these `6` characters, so the `number of bits needed` is `3`

Consider the following encodings:

```
{
'X' : 000,
'X+': 001,
'X_': 010,
'Y':  011,
'Y+': 100,
'Y_': 101,
}
```

And I get to represent the example in a matrix as *(binary representation is vertical)*:

```
X+     Y_    X    X+    Y    Y    Y    Y_
0      1     0    0     0    0    0    1
0      0     0    0     1    1    1    0
1      1     0    1     1    1    1    1
```

Which is why I am looking to combine diacritics with letters first.

---

*Note: [Iterate over a string 2 (or n) characters at a time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162592/iterate-over-a-string-2-or-n-characters-at-a-time-in-python) and [Iterating each character in a string using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538346/iterating-each-character-in-a-string-using-python) do not give the intended answer.*

Comment: is `verse` a `list` or a generator?

Comment: note that `map` works well with builtins. When you have to create your own function, generator comprehension is faster & more readable

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've edited the question, check it :)

Comment: I will have a look on that.

Comment: you'd have more answers by transposing your question with - say - letters and digits rather than arabic characters. Digits may remain arabic :)

Comment: is this more clear :-)?

Comment: Why exactly does it have to be `map` with lambda instead of a `for` loop or any other approach, maybe a list comprehension or something using `groupby`?

Comment: A slightly more wasteful, but more informative encoding would be to take the base letters (29 -> 5 bits), and prepend the diacritic bits (5 as well). You can stash every character in a uint16 number that way. This method requires much less up-front processing, and is not text-dependent. With your method, you could potentially end up with the same text having different encodings depending on how many verses came with it, which seems counter-productive.

Comment: Another advantage of the method I am recommending is that you can do something like allocate the upper two bits to mark start, mid, end and isolated. You can then apply `code & 0x3FFF` to compare without the position indicator.

Comment: I hadn't read your update carefully enough when I calculated the numbers of bits. One last question. What is the range/ranges of the actual letters?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I would love to see an example of your encoding methodology :) I've added the ranges of letters.

Comment: @AndrewNaguib. My work on this question inspired this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54424433/2988730

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to throw my hat into the ring with numpy here. You can convert a string into a useable format with

```
arr = np.array([verse]).view(np.uint32)
```

You can mask the locations where the following character is diacritical:

```
mask = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
np.bitwise_and((arr[1:] > lower), (arr[1:] < upper), out=mask[:-1])
mask[-1] = False
```

Here, the range `[upper, lower]` is a made up way for checking for diacritics. Implement the actual check however you like. In this example, I used the full-blown form of [`bitwise_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) with [`empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) to avoid a potentially expensive append of the last element.

Now if you have a numerical method for encoding your code points to a number, which I'm sure you can vectorize, you can do something like:

```
combined = combine(letters=arr[mask], diacritics=arr[1:][mask[:-1]])
```

To get the remaining, uncombined characters, you would have to remove both the diactitics and the characters they bind to. The easiest way I can think of doing this is smearing the mask to the right and negating it. Again, I assume that you have a vectorized method to encode the single characters as well:

```
smeared = mask.copy()
smeared[1:] |= mask[:-1]
single = encode(arr[~smeared])
```

Combining the result into a final array is conceptually simple but takes a couple of steps. The result will be [`np.count_nonzeros(mask)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzeros.html) elements shorter than the input, since diacritics are being removed. We need to shift all the mask elements by the amount of their index. Here's one way to do it:

```
ind = np.flatnonzero(mask)
nnz = ind.size
ind -= np.arange(nnz)

output = np.empty(arr.size - nnz, dtype='U1')
output[ind] = combined

# mask of unmodified elements
out_mask = np.ones(output.size, dtype=np.bool)
out_mask[ind] = False
output[out_mask] = single
```

The reason I'm suggesting numpy is that it should be able to handle a few million characters in a matter of seconds this way. Getting the output back as a string should be straightforward.

**Suggested Implementation**

I have been pondering your question and decided to play with some timings and possible implementations. My idea was to map the unicode characters in **0x0621-0x063A**, **0x0641-0x064A** (26 + 10 = 36 letters) into the lower 6 bits of a `uint16`, and the characters **0x064B-0x0652** (8 diacritics) to the next higher 3 bits, assuming these are in fact the only diacritics you need:

```
def encode_py(char):
    char = ord(char) - 0x0621
    if char >= 0x20:
        char -= 5
    return char

def combine_py(char, diacritic):
    return encode_py(char) | ((ord(diacritic) - 0x064A) << 6)
```

In numpy terms:

```
def encode_numpy(chars):
    chars = chars - 0x0621
    return np.subtract(chars, 5, where=chars > 0x20, out=chars)

def combine_numpy(chars, diacritics):
    chars = encode_numpy(chars)
    chars |= (diacritics - 0x064A) << 6
    return chars
```

You can choose to encode further to shorten the representation slightly, but I would not recommend it. This representation has the advantage of being verse-independent, so you can compare portions of different verses, as well as not worry about which representation you're going to get depending on how many verses you encoded together. You can even mask out the top bits of all the codes to compare the raw characters, without diacritics.

So let's say that your verse is a collection of randomly generated numbers in those ranges, with diacritics randomly generated to follow one letter each at most. We can generate a string of length around million pretty easily for comparative purposes:

```
import random

random.seed(0xB00B5)

alphabet = list(range(0x0621, 0x063B)) + list(range(0x0641, 0x064B))
diactitics = list(range(0x064B, 0x0653))

alphabet = [chr(x) for x in alphabet]
diactitics = [chr(x) for x in diactitics]

def sample(n=1000000, d=0.25):
    while n:
        yield random.choice(alphabet)
        n -= 1
        if n and random.random() < d:
            yield random.choice(diactitics)
            n -= 1

data = ''.join(sample())
```

This data has completely randomly distributed characters, with approximately a 25% chance of any character being followed by a diacritic. It takes just a few seconds to generate on my not-too-overpowered laptop.

The numpy conversion would look like this:

```
def convert_numpy(verse):
    arr = np.array([verse]).view(np.uint32)
    mask = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    mask[:-1] = (arr[1:] >= 0x064B)
    mask[-1] = False

    combined = combine_numpy(chars=arr[mask], diacritics=arr[1:][mask[:-1]])

    smeared = mask.copy()
    smeared[1:] |= mask[:-1]
    single = encode_numpy(arr[~smeared])

    ind = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    nnz = ind.size
    ind -= np.arange(nnz)

    output = np.empty(arr.size - nnz, dtype=np.uint16)
    output[ind] = combined

    # mask of unmodified elements
    out_mask = np.ones(output.size, dtype=np.bool)
    out_mask[ind] = False
    output[out_mask] = single

    return output
```

**Benchmarks**

And now let's `%timeit` to see how it goes. First, here are the other implementations. I convert everything to a numpy array or a list of integers for fair comparison. I've also made minor modifications to make the functions return lists of the same quantities to validate accuracy:

```
from itertools import tee, zip_longest
from functools import reduce

def is_diacritic(c):
    return ord(c) >= 0x064B

def pairwise(iterable, fillvalue):
    """ Slightly modified itertools pairwise recipe
    s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ... 
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def combine_py2(char, diacritic):
    return char | ((ord(diacritic) - 0x064A) << 6)

def convert_FHTMitchell(verse):
    def convert(verse):
        was_diacritic = False  # variable to keep track of diacritics -- stops us checking same character twice

        # fillvalue will not be encoded but ensures last char is read
        for this_char, next_char in pairwise(verse, fillvalue='-'):
            if was_diacritic:  # last next_char (so this_char) is diacritic
                was_diacritic = False
            elif is_diacritic(next_char):
                yield combine_py(this_char, next_char)
                was_diacritic = True
            else:
                yield encode_py(this_char)

    return list(convert(verse))

def convert_tobias_k_1(verse):
    return reduce(lambda lst, x: lst + [encode_py(x)] if not is_diacritic(x) else lst[:-1] + [combine_py2(lst[-1], x)], verse, [])

def convert_tobias_k_2(verse):
    res = []
    for x in verse:
        if not is_diacritic(x):
            res.append(encode_py(x))
        else:
            res[-1] = combine_py2(res[-1], x)
    return res

def convert_tobias_k_3(verse):
    return [combine_py(x, y) if y and is_diacritic(y) else encode_py(x) for x, y in zip_longest(verse, verse[1:], fillvalue="") if not is_diacritic(x)]
```

Now for the timings:

```
%timeit result_FHTMitchell = convert_FHTMitchell(data)
338 ms ± 5.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit result_tobias_k_1 = convert_tobias_k_1(data)
Aborted, took > 5min to run. Appears to scale quadratically with input size: not OK!

%timeit result_tobias_k_2 = convert_tobias_k_2(data)
357 ms ± 4.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit result_tobias_k_3 = convert_tobias_k_3(data)
466 ms ± 4.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit result_numpy = convert_numpy(data)
30.2 µs ± 162 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

A comparison of the resulting arrays/lists shows that they are equal as well:

```
np.array_equal(result_FHTMitchell, result_tobias_k_2)  # True
np.array_equal(result_tobias_k_2, result_tobias_k_3)   # True
np.array_equal(result_tobias_k_3, result_numpy)        # True
```

I'm using `array_equal` here because it performs all the necessary type conversions to verify the actual data.

So the moral of the story is that there are lots of ways to do this, and parsing a few millions of characters shouldn't be prohibitively expensive on its own, until you get into cross referencing and other truly time-consuming tasks. The main thing to take from this is not to use `reduce` on lists, since you will be reallocating **a lot** more than you need to. Even a simple `for` loop will work fine for your purposes. Even though numpy is about ten times faster than the other implementations, it doesn't give a huge advantage.

**Decoding**

For the sake of completeness, here is a function to decode your results:

```
def decode(arr):
    mask = (arr > 0x3F)
    nnz = np.count_nonzero(mask)
    ind = np.flatnonzero(mask) + np.arange(nnz)

    diacritics = (arr[mask] >> 6) + 41
    characters = (arr & 0x3F)
    characters[characters >= 27] += 5

    output = np.empty(arr.size + nnz, dtype='U1').view(np.uint32)
    output[ind] = characters[mask]
    output[ind + 1] = diacritics

    output_mask = np.zeros(output.size, dtype=np.bool)
    output_mask[ind] = output_mask[ind + 1] = True
    output[~output_mask] = characters[~mask]

    output += 0x0621

    return output.base.view(f'U{output.size}').item()
```

As a side note, the work I did here inspired this question: [Converting numpy arrays of code points to and from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54424433/2988730)

Comment: Could you please clarify the masking part?

Comment: What is the `second` variable?

Comment: Are you sure in `combine(letters=arr[mask], diacritics=arr[1:][mask[:-1]])` it is not `letters=arr[~mask]`, note the `~`.

Comment: @Andrew I'm splitting the array into two portions: character-diacritic pairs and standalone characters. `second` was just `arr[1:]` from a prior edit (fixed now). The mask therefore marks the characters followed by a diacritic. And that means `arr[1:][mask[:-1]]` are the diacritic characters. `arr[~mask]` includes both diacritics and standalone characters.

Comment: @Andrew. Your problem is interesting. I'll run an example on some random data and post a benchmark of this version and the others if I have time today.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear now :) I believe it's a challenging problem for Arabic text analysis. Thank you for that

Comment: @Andrew. Do you have an encoding in mind, or would you like me to recommend one?

Comment: @Andrew. Yeah, Hebrew has the same issue, but you can simply discard the diacritics most of the time.

Comment: Not in my problem, as they represent very important information, that is the pronunciation :)

Comment: I've also added the range of diacritics to the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort:) I believe this will extremely be beneficial to my project. Bounty is awarded after 23 hours:).

Comment: @AndrewNaguib. I've fixed the bug in my answer, as well as making it run ~3x faster than before, making it overall ~10x faster than using Python. I also added a function to decode the encoded text, since I figured you'd need that at some point.

Comment: Haha. I was actually coding it :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

`map` does not seem to be the right tool for the job. You do not want to map characters to other characters, but group them together. Instead, you might try `reduce` (or `functools.reduce` in Python 3). Here, I use `isalpha` to test what kind of character it is; you might need something else.

```
>>> is_diacritic = lambda x: not x.isalpha()
>>> verse = "XXA)L_I!I%M<LLL>MMQ*Q"
>>> reduce(lambda lst, x: lst + [x] if not is_diacritic(x) else lst[:-1] + [lst[-1]+x], verse, [])
['X', 'X', 'A)', 'L_', 'I!', 'I%', 'M<', 'L', 'L', 'L>', 'M', 'M', 'Q*', 'Q']
```

However, this is barely readable and also creates lots of intermediate lists. Better just use a boring old `for` loop, even if you explicitly asked for something else:

```
res = []
for x in verse:
    if not is_diacritic(x):
        res.append(x)
    else:
        res[-1] += x
```

---

By iterating pairs of consecutive characters, e.g. using `zip(verse, verse[1:])` (i.e. `(1,2), (2,3),...`, not `(1,2), (3,4), ...`), you could indeed also use a list comprehension, but I'd still vote for the `for` loop for readability.

```
>>> [x + y if is_diacritic(y) else x
...  for x, y in zip_longest(verse, verse[1:], fillvalue="")
...  if not is_diacritic(x)]
...
['X', 'X', 'A)', 'L_', 'I!', 'I%', 'M<', 'L', 'L', 'L>', 'M', 'M', 'Q*', 'Q']
```

You *could* even do the same using `map` and lambda, but you'd also need to `filter` first, with another lambda, making the whole thing orders of magnitude uglier and harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

You're not reading two characters at a time and even if you were, `map` does not split them into two parameters for `lambda`.

```
from itertools import tee, zip_longest

def pairwise(iterable, fillvalue):
    """ Slightly modified itertools pairwise recipe
    s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ... 
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def encode_arabic(verse):

    was_diacritic = False  # variable to keep track of diacritics -- stops us checking same character twice

    # fillvalue will not be encoded but ensures last char is read
    for this_char, next_char in pairwise(verse, fillvalue='-'):

        if was_diacritic:  # last next_char (so this_char) is diacritic
            was_diacritic = False

        elif is_diacritic(next_char):
            yield encode(this_char + next_char)
            was_diacritic = True

        else:
            yield this_char

encode_arabic(verse)  # returns a generator like map -- wrap in list / string.join / whatever
```

Comment: Is this faster than what I'm looking for? Yeah, I said `I was hoping for` :)

Comment: I see -- How about this version using lazy iterators.

Comment: In fact, with the `pairwise` recipe, you could also use a list comprehension (or even `map` and `filter` with two lambdas, but... ugh): `[x+y if is_diacritic(y) else x for x, y in pairwise(verse, "") if not is_diacritic(x)]`