# Converting numpy arrays of code points to and from strings

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have a long unicode string:

```
alphabet = range(0x0FFF)
mystr = ''.join(chr(random.choice(alphabet)) for _ in range(100))
mystr = re.sub('\W', '', mystr)
```

I would like to view it as a series of code points, so at the moment, I am doing the following:

```
arr = np.array(list(mystr), dtype='U1')
```

I would like to be able to manipulate the string as numbers, and eventually get some different code points back. Now I'd like to invert the transformation:

```
mystr = ''.join(arr.tolist())
```

These transformations are reasonably fast and invertible, but take up an unnecessary amount of space with the `list` intermediary.

Is there a way to convert a numpy array of unicode characters to and from a Python string without converting to a list first?

**Afterthoughts**

I can get `arr` to appear as a single string with something like

```
buf = arr.view(dtype='U' + str(arr.size))
```

This results in a 1-element array containing the entire original. The inverse is possible as well:

```
buf.view(dtype='U1')
```

The only issue is that the type of the result is `np.str_`, not `str`.

Comment: Does `mystr = ''.join(arr.tolist())` runs? Doesn't `arr` need to be an array of strings or something like that?

Comment: How about : `np.frombuffer(mystr,dtype=np.uint8)`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo. Sorry, I removed the `.view(np.uint32)` part since it's pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @Divakar. I thought I'd tried that, but let me double check

Comment: Is there a problem with `''.join(arr)` ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo. Apparently not. I hadn't considered that. What's the inverse of that?

Comment: For the string representation, think it would be : `np.fromstring(mystr, dtype=np.uint8).view('S1')`.

Comment: @Divakar. The only problem is that my actual string has code-points >> 127. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Divakar. I think I would have to call `ord` a bunch of times to get the result you are suggesting, and I was hoping to avoid doing that directly.

Comment: Does `arr = np.fromiter(mystr, dtype='U1')` works for you?

Comment: @DanielMesejo. It works, as long as there aren't any really weird characters. I went ahead and removed them in my last edit.

Comment: @DanielMesejo. I looked at the source code, and it appears that you can supply a `count` argument which will actually pre-allocate the entire buffer. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Divakar. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromiter` works, but is really slow, since it goes through the iterator protocol. It's much faster to encode your data to UTF-32 (in system byte order) and use [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html):

```
In [56]: x = ''.join(chr(random.randrange(0x0fff)) for i in range(1000))

In [57]: codec = 'utf-32-le' if sys.byteorder == 'little' else 'utf-32-be'

In [58]: %timeit numpy.frombuffer(bytearray(x, codec), dtype='U1')
2.79 µs ± 47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [59]: %timeit numpy.fromiter(x, dtype='U1', count=len(x))
122 µs ± 3.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [60]: numpy.array_equal(numpy.fromiter(x, dtype='U1', count=len(x)), numpy.fr
    ...: ombuffer(bytearray(x, codec), dtype='U1'))
Out[60]: True
```

I've used `sys.byteorder` to determine whether to encode in `utf-32-le` or `utf-32-be`. Also, using `bytearray` instead of `encode` gets a mutable bytearray instead of an immutable bytes object, so the resulting array is writable.

---

As for the reverse conversion, `arr.view(dtype=f'U{arr.size}')[0]` works, but using [`item()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) is a bit faster and produces an ordinary string object, avoiding possible weird edge cases where `numpy.str_` doesn't quite behave like `str`:

```
In [72]: a = numpy.frombuffer(bytearray(x, codec), dtype='U1')

In [73]: type(a.view(dtype=f'U{a.size}')[0])
Out[73]: numpy.str_

In [74]: type(a.view(dtype=f'U{a.size}').item())
Out[74]: str

In [75]: %timeit a.view(dtype=f'U{a.size}')[0]
3.63 µs ± 34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [76]: %timeit a.view(dtype=f'U{a.size}').item()
2.14 µs ± 23.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

Finally, be aware that NumPy doesn't handle nulls like normal Python string objects do. NumPy can't distinguish between `'asdf\x00\x00\x00'` and `'asdf'`, so using NumPy arrays for string operations is not safe if your data may contain null code points.

Comment: I am fairly sure that `U1` stands for system byte-order. In my case it translates to `<U1`, but the actual dtype has `byteorder` set to `=`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I was under the impression that the `>` or `<` in a `U` dtype controlled order of code points relative to each other, but apparently it controls byte order within a code point.

Comment: I didn't even know `item` existed. Definitely selecting this answer over mine.

Comment: I've added `arr = np.array([mystr]).view(dtype='U1')` to my answer. It seems to be much faster than any of the other options. And I did check the units this time. It's conceptually a better inverse to `.item()` in my mind, which is nice.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Oh, right, that's an option. I got distracted by complexity and totally forgot you can just pass the string to NumPy directly.

Comment: I never considered it either. Just stumbled onto it by accident :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Actually, it seems to be slower than `frombuffer` in my tests. It's fast enough that I'd still pick it over `frombuffer` for simplicity and being less bug-prone, but it's not actually beating `frombuffer` in speed. I wonder what's causing the difference in our observations.

Comment: I think that the advantage goes away entirely for larger strings. I tested with 100, 10K and 1M, and frombuffer only wins in the first case. I put the timings in my answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: My timings agree with yours. It looks like a size-dependent effect.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way I have found to convert a string to an array is

```
arr = np.array([mystr]).view(dtype='U1')
```

Another (slower) way to convert a string to an array of unicode code points based on [@Daniel Mesejo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424433/converting-numpy-arrays-of-code-points-to-and-from-strings?noredirect=1#comment95660116_54424433):

```
arr = np.fromiter(mystr, dtype='U1', count=len(mystr))
```

Looking at the source code for [`fromiter`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2b05f3e38431842ff06df9b2958d22c5a0588767/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3911) shows that setting the `count` parameter to the length of the string will cause the entire array to be allocated at once, instead of performing multiple reallocations.

To convert back to a string:

```
str(arr.view(dtype=f'U{arr.size}')[0])
```

For most purposes, the final conversion to Python `str` is not necessary since `np.str_` is a subclass of `str`.

```
arr.view(dtype=f'U{arr.size}')[0]
```

**Appendix: Timing of `frombuffer` vs `array`**

*100*

```
mystr = ''.join(chr(random.choice(range(1, 0x1000))) for _ in range(100))

%timeit np.array([mystr]).view(dtype='U1')
1.43 µs ± 27.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit np.frombuffer(bytearray(mystr, 'utf-32-le'), dtype='U1')
1.2 µs ± 9.06 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

*10000*

```
mystr = ''.join(chr(random.choice(range(1, 0x1000))) for _ in range(10000))

%timeit np.array([mystr]).view(dtype='U1')
4.33 µs ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.frombuffer(bytearray(mystr, 'utf-32-le'), dtype='U1')
10.9 µs ± 29.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

*1000000*

```
mystr = ''.join(chr(random.choice(range(1, 0x1000))) for _ in range(1000000))

%timeit np.array([mystr]).view(dtype='U1')
672 µs ± 1.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.frombuffer(bytearray(mystr, 'utf-32-le'), dtype='U1')
732 µs ± 5.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: That's not better scaling. That's 53.4 *milliseconds* compared to 733 *microseconds*.

Comment: @user2357112. I'll see myself out. To a good school. Where I can learn to read.

Comment: I've made the same mistake plenty of times myself.