# Python efficently convert string to numpy integer array, character by character

Tags: python, numpy, performance, encoding, utf-8

NumPy can work with [comma separated lists](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) but that is a different task.
I want to convert each *character* of a string into an entry of a np array:

```
x = np.frombuffer('fooλ'.encode(), dtype=np.uint8) #x = [102 111 111 206 187]
```

But the [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) assigns a variable number of bytes to each char (ascii chars take one byte but unicode chars take up to four). In this example "λ" costs two bytes.

To get the correct answer "ord()" works well:

```
x = np.asarray([ord(c) for c in 'fooλ']) #x = [102 111 111 955]
```

But this solution involves a list comprehension. Doing so is slow since it's not [vectorized](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html): the Python intrepreter has to call ord() on each character instead of calling a function once on the whole string. Is there a faster way?

**Edit:** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424433/converting-numpy-arrays-of-code-points-to-and-from-strings) is very similar, although my answer is much more concise.

Comment: You could use str.encode('utf-16') to encode it using fixed-width 16 bit numbers. However that will still need to use multiple 16 bit numbers if the Unicode code point does not fit in the basic multilingual plane.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424433/converting-numpy-arrays-of-code-points-to-and-from-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that *UTF-32* is the correct answer. **Edit:** the "-LE" means "little endian" and prevents 4 bytes from being prepended.

```
x = np.frombuffer('fooλ'.encode('UTF-32-LE'), dtype=np.uint32) #x = [102 111 111 955]
```

I *think* this is vectorized (for a long string most of the work will be in the C++ functions rather than the Python interpreter). It will cause trouble if UTF-32 ever uses more than 4 bytes however...

Comment: The extra 4 bytes are a byte order mark. You can avoid them by specifying an endianness explicitly: `'fooλ'.encode('UTF-32-LE')`.

Comment: I think you can accept your answer. Currently UTF-32 uses less than 0.1% of its capacity ([11 bits are always 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32))