# Pairwise iteration in list of tuples element

Tags: iteration, pairwise

In python, I'd like to make a pairwise iteration through a list of tuples (lot) element. My lot is shown below:

```
lot = [('490001', 'A-ARM1'),
       ('490001', 'A-ARM2')]
```

I'd like to create **one iteration variable** that loops through the **second element** of every tuple, which will match:

```
iter: A-, AR, M1    (cycle 1)
iter: A-, AR, M2    (cycle 2)
```

On stack I found this ([Iterate over a string 2 (or n) characters at a time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162592/iterate-over-a-string-2-or-n-characters-at-a-time-in-python)).

Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work in my example. Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Can you clarify this a little bit? What do you want your loop(s) to look like? Are your iterators over a single element from the `lot` list, or each one in turn? Are nested loops acceptable?

For Iter1 are you expecting: 49, 00, 01, (end first element) 49, 00, 01 (end second one)

Comment: Thanks for the response bjmc, I adjusted the question for you to make it clearer. Nested loops are acceptable. Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nested loops are acceptable (per your comment), then I think you can use [the grouper recipe from more-itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (or copy-paste that function in your codebase):

```py
from more_itertools import grouper


lot = [('490001', 'A-ARM1'),
       ('490001', 'A-ARM2')]

# Tuple-unpacking w/underscore is a convention to indicate we don't
# care about the first element, only the second one
for _, elem in lot: 
   for i, j in grouper(elem, 2):
       print(i + j)

# Output
# A-
# AR
# M1
# A-
# AR
# M2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bjmc, you've been a great help.